# Laravel - php artisan migrate - SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Tags: php, git, laravel

I have a problem.
I pulled a Laravel project from Git, but I can't migrate the tables with the 'php artisan migrate' command.
The error messages:

> In Connection.php line 664: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open
> database file (SQL: select * from sqlit e_master where type = 'table'
> and name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 67: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database
> file"

My .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

My .env.dusk.local file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ot-admin-dusk
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

In the Sequel pro of course I created the database.

Thanks,

Comment: copy your  .env.dusk.local connection config to .env. See if it works

Comment: try to remove the DB_DATABASE=database variable in your .env file or change the DB_CONNECTION value to mysql instead of sqlite

Comment: Check if your user has privileges into this database

Comment: i think you used config:cache ... run php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to use `sqlite`, remove the `DB_HOST` and `DB_DATABASE` keys from the .env file.
Now create `storage/database.sqlite` and give it the relevant permissions.